# c++ using-declarations For calling function from base class

Tags: c++

Why does `d.f(1)` call `Derived::f` in this code?

Does the `using Base::f` play a role in deciding which `f` will be called?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Base {
    void f(int){
        cout << "\n f(Base) is called" ;
    }
};
struct Derived : Base {
    using Base::f ;    //  using-declarations  but still Drived function is called
    void f(int){
        cout << "\n f(Derived) is called" ;
    }
};
void use(Derived d)
{

    d.f(1);     // calls Derived::f
    Base& br = d ;
    br.f(1);        // calls Base::f
}

int main() {

        Derived d;
        use (d);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `using Base::f` is only for cases, when you don't have an overidden function in `Derived`. As soon you have a declaration/definition there, this one is called.

Comment: Your sample would make more sense, if Base::f and Derived::f have different arguments (Here you hide the one and only (using) function with the derived function)

Comment: When I run your code in VS2013 Update 4, the it calls derived, then base.  Are you saying it calls derived, then derived for you?

Comment: Yeah, it calls derived first, then base.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdd10f796300f63e  Am I misunderstanding the problem?  What is desired here?

Comment: I just edit the question to ensure the real question is stated up front. The initial text was a bit confusing - namespaces aren't really relevant for example

Comment: Oh, okay!  thanks for the clarification.  I will remove my answer then.

Comment: problem is from this point that i was expecting Derived::f  wont be called

Comment: Why did you expect that `d.f(1)` would *not* called `Derived::f`? Is it because the `using Base::f` might 'copy' `Base::f` into `Derived` and therefore it would 'hide' `Derived::f`?

Answer (score 5):

The function  `void f(int)` in the derived class hides the function in the base as they have the same name and parameters.

It is explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration):
Using-declaration introduces a member of a base class into the derived class definition, such as to expose a protected member of base as public member of derived. In this case, nested-name-specifier must name a base class of the one being defined. If the name is the name of an overloaded member function of the base class, all base class member functions with that name are introduced. If the derived class already has a member with the same name, parameter list, and qualifications, the derived class member hides or overrides (doesn't conflict with) the member that is introduced from the base class.